# In the title of 'Mia and Me', who is 'me'?

Tags: names, mia-and-me

The children fantasy franchise [*Mia and Me*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mia_and_Me) (2012) revolves around the eponymous girl Mia who can travel to the parallel world of Centopia by means of a magical bracelet and an (ever-changing) passphrase read from a magic book.

Centopia is inhabited by creatures like elves and unicorns. Mia makes various friends there and helps the indigenous elves save the unicorns from dark powers. In our world, where little time passes during the periods Mia spends in Centopia, we see Mia gradually get to terms with the world around her (at least at first, a boarding school where she is sent after her parents' disappearance).

Now, as mentioned above, the franchise is called *Mia and Me*, and I wonder:

#### Who does the *…and Me* part refer to?

- The entire story is mostly told from Mia's perspective.
- While she does have or find some friends and allies in each world (e.g. her grandfather in the real world, Phuddle, Prince Mo and Yuko in Centopia), none of them constantly joins forces with her for anything she does, let alone switch worlds along with her.
- Mia does not seem to consider her Centopia-persona an alter ego of any kind. Despite having a different appearance (in Centopia, Mia is a winged elf rather than a regular human girl), she readily calls herself Mia also in Centopia and makes no secret of her origin in another world.

So, is the *…and Me* part in the title entirely a breaking-the-fourth-wall thing, referring to the viewer/reader, rather than describing anything in-universe?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mia doesn't consider her human 'Mia' personality to be her true self. As she says in her theme song.

> *"There I'm Mia, ***here I'm me***"*

We can assume that she means

> "There [on the mundane Earth] I'm [boring old] Mia, here [in Centopia] I'm [the real] me"

Comment: Ooh, makes sense. That line doesn't appear in the German version of the lyrics; the closest it gets there is "Here, I can be myself", but that says nothing about *not also* being "Mia" here.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: Maybe, but translated song lyrics have to fit the meter first and only then exactly replicate the original meaning. I have accepted this answer because it makes sense based on Mia's characterization, that she would try to dissociate her Centopia-self from her regular-world-self. Still, I think the franchise doesn't convey this fully, given that she very prominently identifies with the name "Mia" even in Centopia, to the point that I think "I am Mia" (which is actually the first passphrase used to enter Centopia!) would also have been a very fitting title.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - She's still Mia in Centopia, just the best version of her. The true version of her. As 'me' as she can be.

Comment: @Valorum: "Two Mias". "She-Mia and Me-Mia". "Mia and Me-a". I see, it was not an easy choice of titles ;)